# CSS targetting an image surrounded by paragraph text

Tags: css

Is it possible to target images within text as opposed to images that are themselves simply a child of their parent?

For instance, target `img` within

```
<p>my dummy text <img src="someurl.jpg"> more dummy text</p>
```

but not

```
<p><img src="someurl.jpg"></p>
```

I've read https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors but it doesn't seem that text nodes are considered children.

the `:only-child` psuedo selector (as in `img:first-child:only-child`) will target both in the examples above since text isn't considered a child, and yes there is only one child of the `p` which is the `img`

Comment: what you want to achieve after selecting the image? maybe we can do it without selector

Answer (score 0):

You can target `<img>` inside

```
<p>some text <img src="example.jpg"> some text</p>
```

with any selector you can target `<img>` inside

```
<p><img src="example.jpg"></p>
```

CSS selectors define the **elements** to which a set of CSS rules apply and "some text" inside `<p>some text</p>` is not an element.

Comment: Yes, but the `:empty` psuedoselector considers text nodes (white space is also considered to be a text node); has text or children. Seems odd when every other selector only works with non-text nodes. But there is seemingly no 'has text but no children'

Comment: @frumbert, the reason is we cannot target text nodes with selectors. `E:nth-child(n)` selector doesn't take text nodes into account, because it cannot target them anyway. If it did, things would be much more complicated.